# Javascript - the difference between parent.call(arguments) and child.prototype = new parent(arguments)?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, properties, call, prototype

I'm trying to get my head fully wrapped around prototypal inheritance and Javascript's inheritance system.

I'm trying to figure out what the difference would be between these two examples. I'm going to guess that it has to do with the prototype inheritance chain, but I'm having trouble finding information relating the two.

## Example 1 - call()

```
function Vehicle(wheels) {
    this.wheels = wheels;
}

function Car(doors) {
    this.doors = doors;
    Vehicle.call(this,4);
}
```

## Example 2 - prototype

```
function Vehicle(wheels) {
    this.wheels = wheels;
}

function Car(doors) {
    this.doors = doors;
}
Car.prototype = new Vehicle(4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you're initializing your `Car` object to have all the same properties of a new `Vehicle` object. However, it's not "real" inheritance, in the following ways:

```
var car = new Car(2);
car instanceof Vehicle; // => false
```

That's the first thing: `instanceof` won't work. Here's the second:

```
var car = new Car(2);

Vehicle.prototype.drive = function() {
  console.log('vroom!');
};

car.drive(); // throws
```

So that's the second thing: accesses to a `Car` instance won't reach up the prototype chain to `Vehicle`'s prototype.

With that in mind, I'd tend to favor the second approach.

---

That said, you *might* actually want to do *both*, as there could be per-instance initialization logic in your `Vehicle` constructor that you actually want to execute when you initialize a `Car` (and that won't happen just by setting the prototype).

To understand what I mean: in your examples you're always passing `4` as the `wheels` parameter to the `Vehicle` constructor, which makes sense. But suppose we add another parameter that can vary by instance:

```
function Vehicle(wheels, color) {
  this.wheels = wheels;
  this.color = color;
}
```

Now there are two approaches we could take here:

```
function Car(doors, color) {
  this.doors = doors;
  Vehicle.call(this, 4, color);
}

Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
```

Notice here that rather than pass anything to the `Vehicle` constructor when setting `Car`'s prototype, we actually call the constructor explicitly in `Car`. This way we get `color` set properly.

The other approach would be:

```
function Car(doors, color) {
  this.doors = doors;
  this.color = color;
}

Car.prototype = new Vehicle(4, null);
```

That would work too.

Comment: So for example, if we had a "model" property in the Vehicle constructor (set using the function arguments), and a "drive" method, would it be ideal to do vehicle.call(model) in the car constructor, along with setting the prototype to vehicle?

Comment: @Kris: Yep, exactly! I was updating my answer to discuss that as you were commenting.

Comment: If you're going to set the prototype *and* call the parent constructor during initialization, I recommend using `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent)` so that the parent constructor is only called once.

Comment: Sorry if it's veering off-topic from this specific question, but what is the difference (besides browser support) between Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent) and Child.prototype = new Parent() ?

Comment: @Kris: First, I believe you would call `Object.create(Parent.prototype)` as opposed to `Object.create(Parent)`. But in answer to your question, the `Object.create` approach doesn't actually invoke the `Parent` constructor. So it provides the most "classical" inheritance mechanism (since in other OOP languages you don't normally have to *instantiate* a base class just to *define* a child class).

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter adds an internal reference (you can call *proto* if you will) that points to the prototype of the corresponding constructor.

If you run the first example and instantiate two instances of each constructor you will end up having something like the following:

[image]

Things that you need to notice here are:

- The `carsObj` has one additional property that the Car constructor doesn't define. The reason for the is this line `Vehicle.call(this,4);` that you have inside the Car constructor.
- Both the constructors and their instances point to an object that is called prototype; This is where the shared members can be stored (i.e. methods or shared properties). In addition, this allows to create inheritance hierarchies via the prototype chaining.
- Instances of the car object will never be able to access the members of the Vehicle's prototype.

The last bullet point is what restricts up from applying proper inheritance.

Similarly if you run the second example the memory might look like this:

[image]

The difference is quite evident. The prototype property of the Car constructor points to an instance of the Vehicle constructor, and so do all the instances of the Car constructor. This is due to this line `Car.prototype = new Vehicle(4);`.

This structure allows the instances of the Car constructor to access all the properties that are defined on the prototype of the parent class. This is due to how JavaScript traverses th prototype chained when looking for a property.

The shortcoming of this technique is that the Car instances do not inherit any instance properties from the Vehicle constructor. It inherits only the shared members.

A better solution is the combination of the above two techniques; That is:

```
function Vehicle(wheels) {
   this.wheels = wheels;
}

function Car(doors) {
   this.doors = doors;
   Vehicle.call(this, 4)
}

Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle);
```

This way instances of the Car constructor will inherit both the shared and the instance members.

Comment: I think I'm getting it... so without the .prototype, Car can't inherit fixed Vehicle properties and methods ( Vehicle.drive() ), but without the call() it can't set properties that would be different with each instance of Vehicle ( color = this.color )?